# ¿Cuál fue la evolución de la palabra "sujeto"?

Tags: etimología, historia, sustantivos, adjetivos

Actualmente en el DLE se pueden encontrar palabras como *[objeto](https://dle.rae.es/objeto)* y *[sujeto](https://dle.rae.es/sujeto)*. La primera viene del latín *obiectus*, y la segunda del latín *subiectus*. Ambas contenían una 'c' en sus orígenes, que todavía se pueden ver, por ejemplo, en el inglés *object* y *subject*. Sin embargo, en algún momento el español suavizó la pronunciación de ambas palabras (y seguramente muchas otras similares) y la 'c' se acabó perdiendo. Lo curioso es que la palabra *sujeto* además perdió la 'b' del principio (cosa que *objeto* no hizo).

Si nos vamos al CORDE y buscamos, sin especificar ningún tipo de rango encontramos:

- 14913 casos de *sujeto(s)*,
- 997 casos de *subjeto(s)*,
- 60 casos de *sujecto(s)*, y
- 884 casos de *subjecto(s)*.

Dado que de los pasos intermedios hay muchos más casos de *subjeto* que de *sujecto*, me inclino a pensar que primero se perdió la 'c' y luego la 'b' (de hecho *[subjeto](https://dle.rae.es/subjeto)* aún está en el diccionario). ¿Es esto así? ¿Cuál fue la evolución desde *subjecto* hasta *sujeto*? ¿Cuál se perdió primero? ¿En qué época aproximada tuvieron lugar dichas pérdidas? Y de forma relacionada, ¿por qué no se perdió la 'b' en *objeto*?

Comment: Otra pregunta podría ser por qué [_perfecto_](https://dle.rae.es/perfecto) no sufrió la misma evolución y no decimos [_perfeto_](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/Ortografia_kastellana,_nueva_i_perfeta).

Comment: For some reason when I try to say _subjeto_ I have to make a pause (possibly a glottal stop) between the b and the j in a way I do not for _objeto_ so I wonder whether it is the presence of an initial s that makes the difference

Comment: Charlie, there was a general Romance tendency toward perfeto*, witness fr. parfait, ital. perfetto, port. perfeito. I assume "perfecto" was a "learned" or "semi-learned' medieval or later borrowing from Latin, most of which retained close to original Latin form, without the normal phonological changes which occurred in the transition from spoken Latin to Romance and Old Spanish, then modern Castellano. Conflicting forms may have existed. The RAE resolved many of these in the modern form in the late 18th century, with nearly original (Latin) pronunciation and spelling intact. (Penny, 2002)

Comment: @Charlie No me extrañaría que <<perfecto>>, que aparece mucho más frecuentemente que <<sujeto>> en la Biblia (y seguramente en la liturgia aún más) haya resistido mejor esa evolución por esta misma razón.

Answer (score 1):

*Sujeto* y *objeto* no sonpalabras patrimoniales del español (palabras que siempre estuvieron en español y evolucionaron con el resto del léxico), sino que son cultismos (palabras adoptadas del latín y parcialmente adaptadas, seguramente a partir del siglo XIV).

Las variantes *subjeto, subjecto* muestra que hay vacilación sobre cuanto debía adaptarse la palabra. Al tratarse de cultismos, posiblemente introducidos en diferentes momentos, no se respetaron reglas comunes para adaptarlos. De haber sido palabras patrimoniales habrían sufrido la siguiente evolución:

obiectu(m) > *od͡ʒet͡ʃo > *ojecho* (no *objeto*)

subjectu(m) > *sud͡ʒet͡ʃo > *sujecho* (no *sujeto*)